# Target specific player to teleport mob to, for my hide and seek map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to disguise players as mobs.  I need to make sure the mob teleports to only the hider.

`@p` teleports to whoever is closer

`@a` and `@r` don't work either.

I have to give the player invisibility to disguise them and then tp the mob in a repeating command block with the command:

```
/tp @e[type=(mob)] (yourself or @p)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use for [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags).  You can give the player a tag and then use this tag to target that player.  The [command to add a tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags_commands) would be:

```
scoreboard players tag <entity> add <tagName>
```

Change `<entity>` to the player name and `<tagName>` to whatever name you like.

Then your repeat command uses the specified [tag in the target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_tag).  I also recommend adding the [count selector argument](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_count) to prevent more then one mob from teleporting:

```
tp @e[type=TYPE,c=1] @a[tag=TAG]
```

Replace `TYPE` and `TAG`.

To remove the tag from the player:

```
scoreboard players tag <entity> remove <tagName>
```

---

Example commands using 'Hider' as the tag name:

```
/scoreboard players tag IronAnvil add Hider
tp @e[type=cow,c=1] @a[tag=Hider]
/scoreboard players tag IronAnvil remove Hider
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hider team, make the hider join the hider team, and execute your teleport command.

```
scoreboard teams add hider
scoreboard teams join hider (username)
tp @e[type=sheep] @a[team=hider]
```

## Multiple players

The above solution is plausible if you have one player.
I will assume that all of your hiders are on the 'hider' team.
You could do this:

```
execute @a[team=hider] ~ ~ ~ summon sheep ~ ~ ~
```

In a repeat block:

```
execute @a[team=hider] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[c=1,type=sheep] @s
```